# Удаление подстроки

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

В поле можно ввести текст. Если введу:

"Asus P51 v5000 MXS", то должен вырезать и сделать "P51 v50 S";

"Asus P56 x7500 MX G2", то должен вырезать и сделать "P56 x75 G2";

"Asus V40 s6000 MXS", то должен вырезать и сделать "V40 s60 S";

То есть шаблон такой: "`Asus # 00 MX #`" и вместо # - любой текст.
Если текст расположен по-другому, Asus в конец к примеру, ничего не делать.

Answer (score 2):

В идеальном случае

**Выражение**

```
^Asus ([\w]{3}) ([a-z]{1}[\d]{2})[\d]{2} MX ?(.+?)$
```

**Замена**

```
\1 \2 \3
```

**UPD.**

Исходя из задачи, решение не такое уж сложное, достаточно заглянуть в какой-нибудь cheat-sheet по регулярным выражениям. Пояснять группировки и классы символов, думаю излишне.

Comment: Интересно бы краткое пояснение к данной маске.